# Determine which certificate expired

Tags: apache, certificate

Knowing that my apache certificates were to expire, I went through the process of renewing them.  I got them all in place.  My website worked wonderful.  Checking the cert from `IE` showed the new expiration date.  `Perfect`... or so I thought.  When the original expiration date hit, I couldn't access the website.  My log is showing a `Java` cert expired.  I can't find it on my system.

I've done simple things like `find / -name "*.crt"` I've gone through our company admin guide.  I've checked several websites.  But I can't determine where there is an expired cert.  Is there a way to get Java to tell you more information about the error?

> My system info:
>   3 servers: FrontEnd, Middleware, DB.  Using Apache, Tomcat, ecm.  Closed system so I can't copy the log.

```
Error message from log on FrontEnd:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:  java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException:  NotAfter: Sun Feb 01 20:44:51  UTC 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have and `apache http server` normally the ssl certificate is configured in  `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` or in a separate file under `/etc/httpd` directory like `/etc/httpd/sites/vhosts_your_site`. The property is `SSLCertificateFile` defined inside a `<VirtualHost>` tag. You can `grep` for:

```
grep -r "SSLCertificateFile" /etc/httpd/
```

Typically the configuration looks like:

```
<VirtualHost your_ip:443>
   ServerName www.yourdomain.com
   SSLEngine on
   SSLCertificateFile /path_to_your_cds.crt
   SSLCertificateKeyFile /path_to_your_private.key
   SSLCertificateChainFile /path_to_your_cdschain.crt
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

See the [apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) for more details.

Could be also possible to configure a ssl certificate in `tomcat`, however since you've an `apache` I think that it's more probably the configuration is there.

Anyway if you want to check if the ssl certificate is configured under `tomcat` check in the `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/server.xml` file if there is a `<connector>` with attribute `scheme="https"`.

If your connector uses `JSSE` the certificate keystore path is in `<connector keystoreFile='your_ks_path'>`, if you use an `ARP` connector then is in `<connector SSLCertificateFile='your_cert.cer'>`.

For more details take a look at [tomcat ssl documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't you Apache as an SSL Proxy it could be that your Apache is using a certificate which is stored in a Java Keystore File (jks). So you should check for jks files: `find / -name "*.jks"`